# DOM is retaining the id of a div even after replacing it with another div using jQuery .load function of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, materialize

So, I tried really hard to find a solution for it, but couldn't probably due to lack of correct search phrases.
I am loading a materializecss slider inside a modal, which is placed within a div with id `#modalgallery` using jQuery's `.load()` function. This code: `$("#modalgallery").load("openmodal.php?link='directory1/directory2'");` is executed on click of a button. The `openmodal.php` responds with the following code

```
<div id="'.$sliderid.'" class="slider "> //sliderid is a dynamically generated id using the albumname of the folder being loaded into the modal
<ul class="slides green lighten-5">
<li>
<img src="directory1/dirctory2/randomimg1.jpg">
</li>
.
.repeated n times(n is the total no. of available images in directory1/directory2)
.
<li>
<img src="directory1/dirctory2/randomimgn.jpg">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 37) {$("#'.$sliderid.'").slider("prev");} /left
if (e.keyCode === 39) {$("#'.$sliderid.'").slider("next");} //right
if (e.keyCode === 32) {$("#'.$sliderid.'").slider("pause");} //space bar
});</script>
```

The First time it works fine but the problem arises when the button is clicked once more. the problem is not really evident till you start using your arrow keys. on using the right/left arrow the slider skips some images, which I think is because its somehow retaining the images or the whole div in its cache, or its not updating its DOM or something.
Please excuse my English, and Thank you in advance.

One answer to this problem is to add a randomly generated number behind the `sliderid` this way everytime a new slider with a new name is added preventing any conflict beforehand by assigning a new id to each slider everytime they are loaded.

Comment: Do you have a working snippet where this problem can be reproduced? Does it happen with all browsers that you have tried?

Comment: It involves the use of two HTML files I wouldn't be able to reproduce it using code snippet.